# What is the Google link equivalent in Yahoo and Bing?

Tags: search-engines

The link: directive in Google will find all pages which link to a given site. E.g. putting this in Google:
link:stackexchange.com
returns a bunch of sites linking to Stack Exchange.

Is there an equivalent directive in Bing and/or Yahoo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that Bing has one.

See this, https://superuser.com/questions/19164/does-bing-have-advanced-search-operators for more general info on Bings options and how to find them.

Specifically, this page from Bing, http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/ff808421.aspx covers their search options.

Finally, Yahoo probably is a duplicate of Bing since all of their searches comes from the Bing engine.

Answer (score 1):

Bing doesn't appear to recognise the `link:` operator. However you can see links pointing to your site through their webmaster tools (same in Google).

Yahoo, on the other hand, redirects all `link:` queries to its neat [Site Explorer](http://siteexplorer.search.yahoo.com/) tool, which is the most comprehensive for domains you do not own. I don't know how long this will stay online for now that Bing runs their search results.

Another useful source is [Open Site Explorer](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/) by SEOmoz. Their index is small by comparison but you can usually see the most important links.

Incidentally, although Google does technically support `link:`, they never show enough links to be remotely useful.